# Does a minimal DFA with k states imply that there couldn't exist a NFA with less than k states?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

> Does a minimal DFA with k states imply that there couldn't exist a NFA with less than k states?

I was wondering if you could have a NFA with less than k states that generates the same language as a minimal DFA with k states?

Comment: Given that "minimal DFA" means least number of states among DFAs accepting (or generating) a language, you're asking whether "least" actually means "least"? How is there a question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Quite the opposite. In fact, it's possible to find NFAs with $n$ states whose minimal DFA has $\approx 2^n$ states, and this exponential blow-up is *expected*. It's highly uncommon for a minimal DFA to be of roughly the same size as a minimal NFA for the same language.

For instance, consider the language in the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ of words whose $3$rd to last letter is an $a$. It's easy to find a small NFA which solves the problem:

[image]

But a corresponding DFA must have at least $8$ states (do you see why?).

See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/how-to-prove-that-dfas-from-nfas-can-have-exponential-number-of-states) for a more in depth discussion, and [here](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Etal/3261/sp17/expdfa.pdf) for a proof that the DFA for this particular example really does require exponentially many states compared to the NFA.

---

I hope this helps ^_^